# uniform convergence of maxima of function sequence

Tags: uniform-convergence

I have a sequence of functions of continous functions, say

$f_{n,i} \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$
with
$f_{n,i} \to f_i$ uniformly for each $i \in \mathbb{N}$, i.e.
$\sup \limits_x | f_{n,i}(x) - f_i(x) | \to 0$.
$f_i$ is continous as well.

Does this imply that
$\max \limits_{i \leq n} f_{n,i} \to \max \limits_{i \in \mathbb{N} }f_i$ uniformly?

In particular I would have to show that

$\sup \limits_{x}| \max \limits_{i \leq n} f_{n,i}(x) - \max \limits_{i \in \mathbb{N} }f_i(x) | \to 0$

Here is how far I got:

$\begin{align*}
\sup \limits_{x} | \max \limits_{i \leq n} f_{n,i}(x) - \max \limits_{i \in \mathbb{N} }f_i(x) |
& = \sup \limits_{x} | \max \limits_{i \leq n} (f_{n,i}(x) - f_i(x)) - \max \limits_{i > n }f_i(x) | \\
& \leq \sup \limits_{x} | \max \limits_{i \leq n} (f_{n,i}(x) - f_i(x)) | +  \sup \limits_{x} |\max \limits_{i > n }f_i(x) | \\
& \leq \sup \limits_{x} \max \limits_{i \leq n} |  (f_{n,i}(x) - f_i(x)) | +  \sup \limits_{x} \max \limits_{i > n } |f_i(x) |
\end{align*}$

Here the first term converges to $0$ by the uniform convergence of the $f_{n,i}$.
Can I ignore the the second term as taking the limit will run through all the $i \in \mathbb{N}$ anyway?

In fact, by the uniform limit theorem this would prove that taking the maximum of such a sequence $f_{n,i}$ is a continous function.

Answer (score 0):

Careful: if no further asumptions are given, you cannot talk about the maximum. For example, the sequence defined by
\begin{align}
f_n(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{rcl} \dfrac{1}{x} & \text{if} & x >0 \\ \dfrac{1}{n+1} & \text{if} & x = 0
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
uniformly converges on $[0,1]$ to the function that is equal to $0$ at $0$ and $1/x$ at $x>0$. But none of them have a maximum value, neither they are bounded.

Comment: By maximum I mean the pointwise maximum. If I have a sequence of functions $f_n$, then I should have a maximum for each $x$.
For example:
$f_n(x) = x/n$ has a maximum. (Of course, this would always be $f_1(x) $ for $x \in [0,1]$
But you are a totally right, I should have mentioned that the $f_{n,i}$ and the limit $f_i$ are continous. Thank you. I will edit my question.

Comment: Oh right, I see. I'll think about that